# How to not start streaming immediately after creating stream in PyAudio?

Tags: python, audio, portaudio

Here is my code for an asynchronous audio player. The problem is that after `p.open(...)` it's immediately calling the callback function. What do the `start_stream` and `stop_stream` functions do?

```
class AsyncAudioPlayer(object):

    def __init__(self, sampling_frequency, sample_width=2):
        self.p = PyAudio()
        self.buffer = MyBuffer()
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.p.get_format_from_width(width=sample_width), rate=sampling_frequency,
                                  output=True, channels=1, stream_callback=self.on_ready_to_play)
        self.started = False

    def close(self):
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()

    def start(self):
        self.started = True
        self.stream.start_stream()

    def schedule_to_play(self, frame):
        self.buffer.put_frames(frame)
        if not self.started:
            print("Not started. Starting now")
            # self.start()

    def on_ready_to_play(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
        print("frame count is {}, time_info {}, status flags {}".format(frame_count, time_info, status_flags))
        return self.buffer.get_frames(frame_count), paContinue
```

Comment: Is the callback firing once, or repeatedly? Is it perhaps trying to queue up one buffer's worth of data so it can play immediately when you start the stream?

Comment: Would or would it not fire repeatedly depends of paContinue flag. In my opinition it shouldn't fire even once before it specifically told so. And after reading docs of PortAudio I think I'm right.

Answer (score 1):

From the [pyaudio.Stream](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#class-stream) docs:

**start** – Start the stream running immediately. Defaults to `True`. In general, there is no reason to set this to `False`.

So you only need a slight modification to your `pyaudio.PyAudio.open` call:

```
self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.p.get_format_from_width(width=sample_width),
                          rate=sampling_frequency,output=True, channels=1, 
                          stream_callback=self.on_ready_to_play, start=False)
```